# Getting Address Information from Google Places API

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I've been looking to use the Google Places API in one of my projects, but I had a question about it that I couldn't figure out.  Should be very simple, but I can't quite wrap my brain around it.  Here's my issue:

I'm trying to implement an autocomplete field that uses Google Places to find a location, then I want to pass that information through the form and include a location name and address in the form parameters.  I'm assuming I'm going to use Place Details to pass the information on, but how can I look that up given the information from the autocomplete field?  Here's my workflow:

User enters location in autocomplete -> Autocomplete passes address information through form -> User submits form -> Form processing page displays location name and address information.

I'm using PHP for the form processing.  Is there a way I can pass the information through JSON to the form processing page?  Any example code would be helpful.

Thanks!

References I've looked up:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

[Getting full address from business name -- Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209489/getting-full-address-from-business-name-google-maps-api)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing further research, I was able to figure out how to do it.

Using the autocomplete example:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete.html

Then, just passing

```
place.name
place.formatted_address
```

Through the form after the places API pulled it up, I was able to accomplish my goal.  I passed the variables into hidden form fields for processing.  For example:

```
document.getElementById('place-name').value = place.name;
document.getElementById('place-address').value = place.formatted_address;
document.getElementById('place-phone').value = place.formatted_phone_number;
document.getElementById('place-id').value = place.id;
```

Hope this helps someone.