# How to retrieve an address based on name and city of a place in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-places-api, google-sheets-api

I would like to know how to retrieve an address based on name and city of a place in Google Sheets? I have read the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34550057/retrieving-location-address-based-on-place-name-and-city-in-google-spreadsheet/39134229#39134229) and followed the instructions, but the code from the answer in that post generated the following error for me:

> TypeError: Cannot read property "formatted_address" from undefined.
>   (line 8, file "Code")

Going to the linked question above will show you the code in the answer, but here is the short version:

After obtaining a [key](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key) for the *Google Places API*, enter the user defined formula in any cell in Google Sheets as follows:

```
=mapAddress(B1, B2, B3)
```

In the text editor, copy and paste:

```
function mapAddress(place, city, state) {
  var API_KEY = 'yourapikeyhere';
  var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=' +
    place + ' ' + city + ' ' + state + '&key=' + API_KEY;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  obj = JSON.parse(json);
  addr = obj.results[0].formatted_address;
  return addr;
}
```

I do not have a high enough score to post comments on that question, which is why I must ask a new question. Is there a Google Sheets template or add-in that achieves this?

Comment: Please share your codes.

Comment: I have edited my post to provide the code. Going to the referenced post will provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the **Google Places API Web Service** in your Google Apps Script project in the [**Developers Console**](https://console.developers.google.com/apis?project=api-project-220766905003), follow the steps below:

1. In the **Script Editor**, click menu **Resources > Developers Console Project**.
2. Click the link named something like: **YourProjectName - project-id-sveeczngccmxxerwwzx**
3. In the left menu click **Library** and search under the **Google Maps APIs** the option **Google Places API Web Service**
4. At the top of the page click **ENABLE** and **run** the script again.

Comment: Yes, I followed the instructions for enabling the Google Places API Web Service, but had trouble getting this to work for me. I did eventually get it to work after deleting the entire column and starting with a new column. Possibly there was something odd in the formatting of one of the cells.

Comment: Maybe something wrong with value of the place, city or state (maybe some extra spaces?). Your code was fine, the only reason I thought to get that error was if the API wasn't enabled, for example if you log the `response` without enabling the API  with `Logger.log(response)` you get a request denied [(image)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/upMin.png) and inevitable throws the [error](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zZLrl.png) you mentioned because `response` becomes `undefined` and you can't access to the property `formatted_address`. But I'm glad it now works now (:

Comment: Remember you can always test your function by running it directly from the Script Editor just by defining the parameters inside the function like this ([image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iVbwr.png))