# Arugment Error in Google Sheets Custom Function

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a custom script in Google Sheets using  [Retrieving location address based on place name and city in Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34550057/retrieving-location-address-based-on-place-name-and-city-in-google-spreadsheet).  Its is awesome!  I wanted to modify the syntax to use the lat long instead of the city and state.  I came up with the following:

```
function mapAddress(SiteName,LatLong) {
  var Radius = '100';
  var API_KEY = 'XXXXXX';
  var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=' +
SiteName + '&location=' + LatLong + '&radius=' + Radius + '&key=' + API_KEY;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  obj = JSON.parse(json);
  addr = obj.results[0].formatted_address;
  return addr;
}
```

Unfortunately I get an invalid argument in line 6 even though it creates a url that I can post in a browser and get valid results.

```
Invalid argument: 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=BurgerKIng&location= 35.221997,-101.831297&radius=100&key=XXXXXX 
(line 6).
```

I have tried encoding the url but nothing helps.  I am a newbie coder but this is about to drive me nuts.  Would you be kind enough to help?

Comment: I have my own api key for this api - and I cant reproduce the error even with the same exact query I get results :-/

Comment: could it be theres a space in location= 35....

Comment: @Abdul Hasan, thanks you so much!!! Yes there was a space, not in the code but in the source data.  I stared at this for an hour.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

For posterity and to close the question: you noted in a comment that there was a space in the source data, resulting in a space after the `=` in the URL. Removing this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was "could it be theres a space in location= 35.." as I mentioned in my comment. You can accept this as the answer for others to see.